# Given the following constraints, can this set be infinitely large?

Tags: set-theory

I am studying a set $X$ with the following properties. Let $x_{i}$ denote the $i^{th}$ element in $X$. Let $n$ denote the cardinality of $X$ ($ = |X|$). The following properties apply:

a) $X$ is a set of positive integers, the values of which must not exceed $2n$.
b) No element $x_{i}$ in $X$ is allowed to divide any other element $x_{j}$ in $X$.

I am curious as to the maximum number of integers (or maximum cardinality) that set $X$ can possess.

If we force $x_{1} = n$, set $n \ge 3$ and ensure that $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt ... \lt x_{n}$. Then provided that each successive element is one greater than the last, can't $X$ contain all elements from $x_1$ up to but not including the element whose value is $2 \cdot x_1$? In turn, would this mean that $X$ can be infinitely large given $n$ is arbitrary? [You can check easily why it is best to start at $x_1 = n = 3$; If $x_1=1$ or $x_1=2$ you can't add many further integers to the set without violating a) or b)]

For example, let's take $n = 3$. Then set $X$ contains three successive integers starting at  $x_1 = n = 3$. So
$X = \{3, 4, 5\}$. Here, the conditions are met that all elements are less than $2n$. If we add the next integer ($6$) then $x_n = 2\cdot x_1$ and hence $x_1$ divides $x_n$ which violates b).

For any $n \ge 3$, $x_1 = n$, we can let S contain all the integers whose values do not exceed $2\cdot x_1$. As another example, take $n=20$, then the rule is to start with $20$ and include all elements less than $2(20) = 40$. So $X = \{20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39\}$.

And indeed $X$ contains $n$ elements with conditions a) and b) satisfied.

Hopefully now you understand my logic and thought process to this problem. As it seems, the cardinality of $X$ can be arbitrarily large provided we make $n$ arbitrarily large, set $x_1 = n$ and count up one at a time until we reach the element $x_n$ which has a value that is 1 less than $2 \cdot x_1$. My reasoning here feels a bit messy though. If indeed my logic is correct, is there a more formal way to prove that $X$ can be infinitely large in this scenario since we can make $n$ arbitrarily large?

Hope I have been clear. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Define $X_n = \{j \in \mathbb{N} \mid n < j \leq 2n\}$. Then $|X_n| = n$, all elements of $X_n$ are $\leq 2n$, and no element of $X_n$ is a proper factor of another.

Comment: Arbitrarily large and infinitely large are different things.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Wainfleet has said, "Arbitrarily large and infinitely large are different things."

If $n$ is a natural number, then it is finite. So if $|X| = n$, then $X$ is a finite set. Alternatively, the set of all positive integers $\le 2n$ is finite, and $X$ is a subset of that. A subset of a finite set is also finite. So again, $X$ is finite.

It doesn't matter that $n$ can be arbitrarily large. $X$ is not a single set. What set it is depends on $n$ (and even for a fixed $n$, there are many possible sets $X$). By choosing a larger $n$, you get a larger $X$, but that $X$ is still a finite set. As you've already discovered, for each positive $n$, the set of all numbers between $n$ and $2n - 1$ meets all your conditions to be $X$. Thus there is at least one such $X$ for any $n$.

Can $n$ be an infinite cardinal, instead of a natural number? Yes. Though $\{ k\in \Bbb N\mid n \le k < 2n\}$ no longer works as an example, since $n$ and $2n$ are not integers. Instead, you can let $X$ be the set of prime numbers.

Comment: If X is the set of prime numbers then it can contain at most 7 elements. Since {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17} would violate condition a).

Comment: @rainingagain - If $X$ is the set of prime numbers, then $n = |X| = \aleph_0$, the least infinite cardinal. As $17$ is an integer, it is most certainly does NOT exceed $2\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$. Did you not note that the paragraph in question started by saying that $n$ *can* be an infinite cardinal?

Comment: Apologies, I see that now. Nonetheless, would X in this case not need to be the set of prime numbers excluding 1 and 2? Condition b) states that no element may divide another element.

Comment: $1$ is not prime, so it is not in $X$. $2$ is prime, and by the definition of prime, any other number it divides is not prime, and so would not be in $X$. The only numbers in $X$ are integers. That does not include $2\aleph_0$.